# What is the best way to handle items visibility per user?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for the best or a good way to handle items visibility per user.
Actually I've the following entities...

```
public class Post
{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Content {get; set;}
  public Guid VisibilityId {get; set;}
  public Visibility Visibility {get; set;}
}
public class Visibility
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class AllowedList
{
  public Guid PostId {get; set;}
  public Guid UserId {get; set;}
}
```

I added the following lookups for the Visibility Entity

```
Public, OnlyMe, Custom
```

I want to display post items for user in cases

1. "public" in that case all users allowed to show that Post.
2. "Custom" in that case the user if exist on the **AllowedList** then they can show it.
3. "OnlyMe" in that case the created user only can show that Post.

so based on that acceptance criteria, I created the following code.

```
/*
    1. PublicId => 1,
    2. OnlyMeId => 2,
    3. CustomId => 3
 */

public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts(ApplicationContext context ,ICurrentUser user)
{
   var userId = user.Id;
   var posts = context.Posts.Where(p => p.VisibilityId == 1 || (p.VisibilityId  == 2 && p.CreatedBy == userId) || context.AllowedList.Any(a => a.PostId == p.Id && a.UserId == userId));
   return posts; // return as IQueryble of Posts
}
```

That's my Solution but I don't think that is the correct or good one for that case.

Comment: Please don't use discards (`_`) when range variables are meaningful. Here they're especially confusing because you also use `__`. Then, you don't *think* it's correct, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a Boolean `IsPublic` should be enough to formulate all cases, since the creator should always be allowed to see the post. `OnlyMe` would correspond to `Public == false` with an empty allowed list. If `Public` is true, it doesn't matter whether there are entries in the allowed list or not.

```cs
public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
```

```cs
var posts = context.Posts
   .Where(p => p.IsPublic ||
               p.CreatedBy == userId ||
               context.AllowedList.Any(a => a.PostId == p.Id && a.UserId == userId));
```

Comment: Yes, The creator should be always allowed to see the post. thanks for help